# Double Integral Using Joint Normal PDF.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$∫_{a}^b ∫_{c}^d\frac{xy}{2{σ_x} {σ_y} \sqrt{1-ρ^2}} e^\left(\frac{-1}{2(1-ρ^2)}\left(\left(\frac{x-{μ_x}}{{σ_x}}\right)^2+\left(\frac{y-{μ_y}}{{σ_y}}\right)^2-\frac{2ρ\left(x-{μ_x}\right)\left(y-{μ_y}\right)}{{σ_x} {σ_y}}\right)\right) dxdy$$
Can this double integral be simplified in terms of standard mathematical functions?

Comment: I can give a recipe.  First shift x and y by $x'=x-\mu_x \ and\ y'=y-\mu_y$.  Next rotate (x',y') so that $\rho =0$.  The resultant double integral should be expressible in terms of the error function.

Comment: Thanks Herb, I appreciate your comment. Do you mean to perform a whitening (sphering) transformation? If so, by what factor would I need to multiply the resultant double integral so that it is numerically equivalent to the double integral I started with?

Comment: What I meant was that by a linear change of variables the random variables X' and Y' can be replaced by a pair of uncorrelated normal random variables.  This transforms the exponent of e into a sum of squares of the two variables with no cross term.